# How can I set a string property from Console.ReadLine() inside a foreach loop?

Tags: c#

I'm a newbie to programming and teaching myself. I am trying to wrap my head around simple multiplayer games using C#. I have a class Player with a single property of Name. I am trying to get the number of users from console input, create an array of the Player object of the size of that input, then for each object in the array ask the user to enter their name. When I try it, I get an object reference not set to an instance of an object error.

Here is my code:

```
using System;

namespace Multiplayer
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("How many players?");
            int NumOfPlayers = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Player[] Players = new Player[NumOfPlayers];
            NameGetter(Players);     
            
        }
        static  void NameGetter(Player[] ListOfPlayers)
        {
            foreach(var player in ListOfPlayers)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("What is Your Name? ");
                player.Name = Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }


}
```

I feel like I might be missing something fundament about OOP in my approach here.

Thanks very much in advance for any help I can get on this one!

Comment: When you write Player[] Players = new Player[NumOfPlayers]; it just creates an array of Players but they are all null. If you want your Players array to contain players you can reference the name property of, you have to first initialize each element in the array to a new Player().

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if you see on the image, Know your array has 3 player types with the null value. so you must first create an object on here.

[image: Your Code]

**But **

[image: You can't assign iteration variable]

> You can change Getter Method like

```
    static void NameGetter(Player[] ListOfPlayers)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ListOfPlayers.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("What is Your Name? ");
            ListOfPlayers[i] = new Player
            {
                Name = Console.ReadLine()
            };
        }
    }
```

[Github Codes](https://github.com/thisisnabi/Stackoverflow-Helps/tree/master/CSharp_PlayerOOP)

Comment: Please don't post images of code. Post the code. Not everyone uses your particular IDE.

Comment: it's for learning. I post the True code in the end!!!!

Comment: your welcome. accept  my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

You've constructed an array of type `Player`, but you haven't constructed the Player objects eg:
`Players[0] = new Player();` will construct the first one, but you'll want to construct them in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to create your array with `Enumerable.Range` like this:

```cs
Player[] players = Enumerable.Range(0, NumOfPlayers).Select(x => new Player()).ToArray();
```